# Using Rewrite URL in apache...i need some suggestions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Actually am trying to do php application without showing the .php extension...i can achieve that by adding .htaccess file within the root folder of the application....but i cant able to get the get request datas from the url so can anyone please help me...
this is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

i can able to send datas like : http://test.dev/?123=123
i can get 123 as var and 123 as value...
but i need to send data like : http://test.dev/123...
i need to get the 123 value in the get array....
please anyone suggest me to achieve this....

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming index.php is handling the data and query variable and value both to be same, try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?$1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: **need to remove the whole rules then add these 4 lines or else replace my rules with your rules...**

Comment: Other that `rewriteengine on` line, write all the lines after your current rules and check then let me know.

Comment: sorry i cant able to get the key and value as same in the get request....

Comment: Are you getting the data in index.php or is there some other file?

Comment: ya am using the index.php to get the GET,POST value for testing purpose....

Comment: What is the error are you getting? if you see here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it is working correctly.

Comment: Thank Your for the Suggestion @abhishek